# What's the difference between an object and a data object?

Tags: singleton, kotlin

The other day I noticed that I sometimes put `data` in front of `object`s and other times not:

```
object A

data object B
```

What's the difference between an `object` and a `data object`?

Answer (score 13):

`data` object is a feature available since Kotlin 1.9.0. It is aimed to solve several inconsistencies in how algebraic data types are declared in Kotlin. The main behavioral difference from regular objects is that `data` object's `toString` returns the short name of the object (see [KT-4107](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4107)).

See more info in the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#data-objects) or in the [KEEP proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/data-objects/proposals/data-objects.md).

Comment: data objects are no longer considered bugs in kotlin version  1.9, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76643924/object-and-data-object-in-kotlin for details