# Object and Data Object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I was writing these 3 Game States inside a Sealed class:

```kotlin
sealed class Status {
    object Idle : Status()
    object Active : Status()
    object GameOver : Status()
}
```

The IDE is suggesting I should use a `data object` instead of `object`.

[image]

The problem is that I have never heard of `data object`. I looked around and did not find a solid explanation in relation to `data object`. For instance, this [2015 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32295251/7839518) suggests this is a bug!

I am looking for your thinking about  `data object` and its usages.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to [Enum](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html)?

Comment: @shahkalpesh not really, it is the sealed class that I need but I just wanted to understand what is a `data object` as I haven't come across it before.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I eventually found some solid info on **Data Objects** from the [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#data-objects)

When you precede an ordinary object with **`data modifier`** you are simply adding some features similar to those of Data Classes to the plain object. For instance a `toString()` is automatically generated for you such that when you print `data object` you get human readable name of the class without ***@address***.

The docs do indeed recommend using a `data objects` to go along with data classes in your sealed class.

> data object declarations are a particularly useful for sealed
> hierarchies, like sealed classes or sealed interfaces, since they
> allow you to maintain symmetry with any data classes you may have
> defined alongside the object:

In summary adding `data` modifier enhances a plain object to have `toString()`, `equals()/hashCode() pair` under the hood. The enhanced object will then match the workings of `Data Classes` in the sealed class hierachy.

**NB** - Unlike the data classes, data object don't have `copy()`  *- objects are singletons with one instance -* and `componentN()`  *- objects don't have properties and cannot be destructured -*  functions

Comment: Worth noting that data object requires languageVersion to be at least 1.9

See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-compiler-options.html#example-of-setting-a-languageversion